# WPF TreeView, adding items on TreeViewItem.Expanded crashes

Tags: c#, wpf, treeview

I have to dynamically load data when the user expands the treeview.

My code looks like this.

XAML:

```
<TreeView 
   ItemsSource="{Binding MasterList}"
   x:Name="treeViewOrg"
   TreeViewItem.Expanded="TreeViewItem_Expanded"
   VirtualizingStackPanel.IsVirtualizing="True" 
   VirtualizingStackPanel.VirtualizationMode="Recycling">
```

CS:

```
private void TreeViewItem_Expanded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    TreeViewItem tvi = e.OriginalSource as TreeViewItem;
    if (tvi != null)
    {
        try
        {
            HybridOrganAndBuddy org = tvi.DataContext as HybridOrganAndBuddy;

            if (org.part_code != null)
            {
                loadFriendData(org.part_code, org);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ee)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ee);
        }
    }
}
```

The loadFriendData method loads data from the server via http post and adds it to the list, which is binded as 'MasterList'.

But the application crashes right after I try this.

The Error trace states like this :  (I translated it from my local language)
System.InvalidOperationException : The ItemsControl does not match its

Any tips will be welcomed.

Comment: "But the application crashes right after I try this" Any error message or exception being thrown?

Comment: When you use the `as` operator, the result may be `null`. You must not ignore that. Check `org` for null after `org = tvi.DataContext as HybridOrganAndBuddy`.

Comment: @MindSwipe  It's in my local language. If i translate it, "System.InvalidOperationException: 'ItemsControl' does not match the source ".

Comment: Please edit your question to add the error message with details of where it's being thrown

Comment: I see you edited your question, but where is the exception being thrown? On which line is it being thrown?

Comment: @MindSwipe the node I just expanded contains three childs, and the loadFriendData loads two more. After I load and add two items to the sub node, It says that the original data was 3, but currently is 5, so it will crash... I can't figure out the specific line since it just crashes after I add all the items I need.

Comment: Ok, remove the try catch. When it throws the exception, Visual Studio will show you exactly on which line the exception was thrown

Comment: @MindSwipe I already have.. I think it's about some internal error that has something to do with data binding. No stacktrace links to my code.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193634/discussion-between-mindswipe-and-march3april4).

Comment: Do you use background thread to retrieve the contents?

Comment: The issue was just about the ViewModel. I changed the viewModel's List to a ObservableCollection, and it started to work. I really don't understand why this happenned.